# Joda Time formats time at 24:xx:xx UTC should be 0:xx:xx UTC

Tags: datetime, blackberry, jodatime

I'm converting from a local time zone to UTC so when we convert

2010-01-03T11:15:58.840+11:00 => Sun, 03 Jan 2010 24:15:58 UTC

This is technically correct but I'm having problems with the 24 hour formatting as it does. I have some BlackBerry J2ME code which is having problems parsing this date-time String using HttpDateParser.

```
new Long(HttpDateParser.parse("Sun, 03 Jan 2010 24:15:58 UTC")
```

Shouldn't this really be "Sun, 03 Jan 2010 0:15:58 UTC"? If I pass in this new date String it will parse just fine. I'd rather not do a nasty "search and replace", but fix the problem at the server.

Question: Is it possible to stop Joda from displaying times as "24:xx:xx" and instead format as "0:xx:xx"?

Edit: I'm formatting the output date as

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FMT =
      new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss zzz");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this format (**HH** instead of **kk**):

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FMT =
  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

That information is in the [SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

[Joda’s formatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) has similar pattern format.